# Add .vtt track from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have a simple vtt track file editor where the built vtt file content is held in `var vtt`.

Currently I add the track by saving the content of `vtt` to file, then reading the file as `<track src='mynewvttfile.vtt' />`

I would like to omit the step of saving to file, and just read the variable content directly into the `<track>` element. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the addTextTrack JS API. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/QZJTM/):

```
//add a subtitle track to a video
var track = $('video')[0].addTextTrack('subtitles', 'just a test', 'en');
//make it visible
track.mode = 'showing';

// add some cues to show the text
track.addCue(new VTTCue(0.5, 5, "My first Cue"));
```